# ggplot2 - jitter and position dodge together

Tags: r, ggplot2, position-dodge

I am trying to recreate a figure from a GGplot2 seminar http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42707925/ggplot2/ggplot2slides.pdf.

In this case, I am trying to generate Example 5, with jittered data points subject to a dodge.  When I run the code, the points are centered around the correct line, but have no jitter.

Here is the code directly from the presentation.

```
set.seed(12345)
hillest<-c(rep(1.1,100*4*3)+rnorm(100*4*3,sd=0.2),
       rep(1.9,100*4*3)+rnorm(100*4*3,sd=0.2))
rep<-rep(1:100,4*3*2)
process<-rep(rep(c("Process 1","Process 2","Process 3","Process 4"),each=100),3*2)
memorypar<-rep(rep(c("0.1","0.2","0.3"),each=4*100),2)
tailindex<-rep(c("1.1","1.9"),each=3*4*100)
ex5<-data.frame(hillest=hillest,rep=rep,process=process,memorypar=memorypar, tailindex=tailindex)
stat_sum_df <- function(fun, geom="crossbar", ...) {stat_summary(fun.data=fun, geom=geom, ...) }

dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.9) 
p<- ggplot(ex5,aes(x=tailindex ,y=hillest,color=memorypar)) 
p<- p + facet_wrap(~process,nrow=2) + geom_jitter(position=dodge) +geom_boxplot(position=dodge)  
p
```

Comment: Given that Didzis Elferts has provided a better answer using `position_jitterdodge` available in ggplot2 version 1.0.0, you should un-accept my answer and accept the answer provided by Didzis Elferts.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**EDIT**: There is a better solution with `ggplot2` version 1.0.0 using `position_jitterdodge`. See @Didzis Elferts' answer. Note that `dodge.width` controls the width of the dodging and `jitter.width` controls the width of the jittering.

I'm not sure how the code produced the graph in the pdf.

But does something like this get you close to what you're after?

I convert `tailindex` and `memorypar` to numeric; add them together; and the result is the x coordinate for the `geom_jitter` layer. There's probably a more effective way to do it. Also, I'd like to see how dodging `geom_boxplot` and `geom_jitter`, and with no jittering, will produce the graph in the pdf.

```
library(ggplot2)
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.9)
ex5$memorypar2 <- as.numeric(ex5$tailindex) + 
  3 * (as.numeric(as.character(ex5$memorypar)) - 0.2) 

p <- ggplot(ex5,aes(x=tailindex , y=hillest)) +
   scale_x_discrete() +
   geom_jitter(aes(colour = memorypar, x = memorypar2), 
     position = position_jitter(width = .05), alpha = 0.5) +
   geom_boxplot(aes(colour = memorypar), outlier.colour = NA, position = dodge) +
   facet_wrap(~ process, nrow = 2)
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I wish there was an elegant way within ggplot2, but this workaround gets everything done.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 75):

In `ggplot2` version `1.0.0` there is new position named `position_jitterdodge()` that is made for such situation. This postion should be used inside the `geom_point()` and there should be `fill=` used inside the `aes()` to show by which variable to dodge your data. To control the width of dodging argument `dodge.width=` should be used.

```
ggplot(ex5, aes(x=tailindex, y=hillest, color=memorypar, fill=memorypar)) +
      facet_wrap(~process, nrow=2) +
      geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=0.9)) +
      geom_boxplot(fill="white", outlier.colour=NA, position=position_dodge(width=0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this post. this is very helpful. I am currently writing my own code, which is working well. But, I somehow get black colour for outliers. Can you guess what could be potential causes?

Comment: Black color is default color for outliers. In this code for `geom_boxplot()` `outlier.colour=` is set to `NA` to not show them.

Comment: Hi, I just found the solution. `outlier.colour` has to be spelled colour, not color. It seems that American spell is not favoured here. Thanks for your reply. :-)

Comment: @DidzisElferts, `outlier.colour = NA` does not work in case of Rshiny/plotly display. is there any workaround?

Comment: You can also try use color ‘transparent’