# In R, how to make the jitter (geom_jitter()) stay inside its correspondant boxplot without extending over the neighboring boxplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, jitter

I would like to find a way for the jitter to stay in its own boxplot, without extending over the neighboring boxplots.

So far, I looked at this answers:

- [R- Group jitter in factored boxplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017265/r-group-jitter-in-factored-boxplot)
- [Understanding boxplot with ‘jitter’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630045/understanding-boxplot-with-jitter)
- [ggplot2 - jitter and position dodge together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493084/ggplot2-jitter-and-position-dodge-together)

but none of them really addressed my issue; the main difference is that I have 3 groups running through a timeline on the X-axis.

**The code I have so far:**

```
ggplot(longitudinal, mapping= aes(x = Time, y = Values), shape= Diagnose)+
geom_boxplot(aes(color = Diagnose), outlier.shape = NA ) +
geom_jitter(aes(color= Diagnose, shape=Diagnose)  ,alpha = 0.5)
```

**The image output:**
[image]

As you can see, the jitter obeys the Timepoint distribution (T0, T1, T2, T3), but when it comes to the diagnosis(Diagnose), it overlaps with the other boxes.

***Here is an example of how my data looks like:***

```
structure(list(Time = c("T0", "T0", "T0", "T0", "T0", "T0", "T0", 
"T0", "T0", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T3", "T3", "T3", 
"T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3"), Diagnose = c("PDD", "PDD", 
"PDD", "PD-MCI", "PD-MCI", "PD-MCI", "PD", "PD", "PD", "PD", 
"PD", "PD-MCI", "PD-MCI", "PD-MCI", "PDD", "PDD", "PDD", "PD", 
"PD", "PD", "PD-MCI", "PD-MCI", "PD-MCI", "PDD", "PDD", "PDD", 
"PD", "PD", "PD", "PD-MCI", "PD-MCI", "PD-MCI", "PDD", "PDD", 
"PDD"), Values = c(13.47, 14.25, 15, 20, 19.57, 15, 15, 17.54, 
18, 16.93, 11.42, 18, 15, 19.48, 15, 11, 15, 18.03, 11, 15, 17.85, 
19, 15, 15, 17.85, 20, 15, 19, 14.11, 12, 18.31, 16, 17.36, 20, 
12)), row.names = c(NA, -35L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

**and this the output when using position = position_jitter() , position=position_jitterdodge(), position_dodge, position_jitterdodge(dodge.width= ) etc  ...**
[image]
As you can see, this packs all the jitter in the central boxplots.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share an example of your data using `dput(longitudinal)`?

Comment: @neuron yes, good idea!  I already updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost! what you are looking for is `geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge())`. You can also adjust the width with `jitter.width`

```
 ggplot(df, mapping= aes(x = Time, y = Values))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = Diagnose), outlier.shape = NA ) +
  geom_point(aes(color= Diagnose, shape=Diagnose), alpha = 0.5, 
                 position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.1))
```

[image]

Comment: This is it! Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Specify the dodge width

`+ geom_jitter(width = 0.05)`

or
`geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.05))`

Comment: This doesn't work. I updated my question to make it clearer. The problem with this is that it packs all the jitter in the middle. And what I am looking for is: the jitter from each diagnosis to stay inside its corresponding boxplot.