# R - plotting geom_point on top of geom_boxplot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, boxplot, points

I'm having trouble plotting a `geom_point()` layer on top of a `geom_boxplot()` layer in `ggplot2`, and have done some research and there don't seem to be any reported issues precisely of this nature. There are 3 factors in my data set: `name`, `genotype`, and `region`, and my response variable is `volume`.  I have working code to produce a plot with both layers.  The problem is that the points ignore the `fill` factor for `geom_point()`, but not for `geom_boxplot()`. The result is that the points are all plotted in the middle of a set of boxplots for each value of `name`.  Here is my code for constructing the plot.

```
meansPlot = ggplot(data=meansData,aes(x=factor(name), y=volume, fill=factor(genotype)))
meansPlot = meansPlot + 
geom_boxplot() +
geom_point() +
facet_wrap( ~ region, scales='free')
```

My apologies for not creating a reproducible data set -- I am not really well versed in simulating data quite yet.  If there isn't an easy answer (which, I expect there is, and I'm probably just missing something), I will add simulated data to help answer the question.

Thanks!

Comment: `fill` doesn't apply to points (generally), but `color` does. So you have to use `color` with the points. Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10493084/324364) might be a good reference (just use `fill` for the boxplots).

Comment: You may have a look at different plot symbols [**here**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/). For `pch` 21-25 you may specify a fill colour.

Comment: Thanks for the reference joran.  It turned out to be really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up mostly solving it.  This code staggers `geom_point()` to be inline with `geom_boxplot()`.

```
meansPlot = ggplot(data=meansData, aes(x=name, y=volume, fill=genotype, color=genotype))  
meansPlot = meansPlot +
geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=0.9)) +
geom_boxplot(fill="white", position=position_dodge(width=0.9), alpha=0.5) +
facet_wrap( ~ region, scales='free')
```

Thanks everybody for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

`geom_point()` should use the `color` attribute, not the `fill` attribute (unless you are using unusual `shape`s).  See if this works for you:

```
meansPlot = ggplot(data=meansData,aes(x=factor(name), y=volume, fill=factor(genotype)), color = factor(genotype))
meansPlot = meansPlot + 
geom_boxplot() +
geom_point() +
facet_wrap( ~ region, scales='free')
```

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't work.  Interestingly though, now at least some of the points have the correct horizontal alignment.

Comment: Also, whenever the plot is made I get the following warning:

`Warning in levels<-(*tmp*, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated`