# Whisker plots to compare mean and variance between clusters

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a clustering over a dataset with N variables:

```
data(iris)
df <- iris[,1:4]
fit <- kmeans(df, 3)
```

I would like to visualise the results using whisker plots, where:

- x-axis corresponds to variables or dimensions.
- boxes indicate the cluster mean (horizontal line) and the variance of the group.
- For every x value (variable) there are `k` boxes, one per group.
- Data points are also shown.

I get to this:

```
points <- df
points$cluster <- fit$cluster
points <- melt(points, id='cluster')

p <- ggplot(points, aes(x=variable, y=value)) 
p <- p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(cluster)))
p <- p + geom_jitter(aes(color=factor(cluster)))
print(p)
```

[image]

But the jitter points should be aligned in with their corresponding boxes. How can I do it?

Comment: About the jittered points see this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493084/ggplot2-jitter-and-position-dodge-together). Is the position of points your only problem?

Comment: Yes, the position is my only problem now (thanks, I'm looking into your link)