# ggplot geom_jitter behind (multiple) geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, jitter

i use following code:

```
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(colour=factor(gear)), width = 0.1) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(gear)), alpha=0.6)
```

with following result:
[image]

But i want the colored dots from geom_jitter directly behind the corresponding(!) boxplot. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: So you want both jittering and dodging?  You can use `position_jitterdodge` for that.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493084/ggplot2-jitter-and-position-dodge-together)

Comment: Thanks. position_jitterdodge within geom_point works well.

Answer (score 5):

Solution is position_jitterdodge as mentioned by aosmith and his link.

```
library(ggplot2)

data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg, fill=factor(gear), colour=factor(gear))) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge()) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.6)
```

The result looks like:
[image]